# Uniformly distribute elements in an javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object of arrays as such:

```
var titles = {
                "Part 1":
                    [
                        ["1", "Title 1",A],
                        ["2", "Title 2",B],
                        ["3", "Title 3",C],
                        ["4", "Title 4",D],
                        ["5", "Title 5",E]
                      
                    ],
                "Part 2":
                    [
                        ["6", "Title 6", A1],
                        ["7", "Title 7", B1],
                        
                    ],

                "Part 3":
                    [
                        ["8", "Title 8", A2],
                        ["9", "Title 9", B2],
                        ["10", "Title 10", c2]
                    ]
            };
```

From, this object I need to construct 3 arrays and put them in a result object. Since Part 1 contains highest number of values (5), I need to construct the arrays of size 5.
If Part 2 and Part 3 also contained 5 values, then it would have been an ideal scenario. But sometimes, I do get the cases where part 2 and part3 are not of size 5. In those cases, I need to distribute values uniformly.

```
 Part 1:
        [
            ["1", "Title 1",A],
            ["2", "Title 2",B],
            ["3", "Title 3",C],
            ["4", "Title 4",D],
            ["5", "Title 5",E]
          
        ],
Part 2:
        [

            ["6"],
            ["7",],
            ["8", "Title 6",A1],
            ["9", "Title 7",B1],
            ["10"]

        ]
    
          

and Part 3:
        [

            ["11"],
            ["12", "Title 8",A2],
            ["13", "Title 9",B2],
            ["14", "Title 10",C2],
            ["15"]
        ]
```

I tried by following way:

```
var maxSize = 5; 

const every_nth = (arr, nth) => arr.filter((e, i) => i % nth === nth - 1);

//Suppose we already have part1Array whose size is 5

let lengthPart1Array = part1Array.length+1;
let total_no_elements_part_2= 2;

let part2Array = every_nth([1,2,3,4,5],Math.floor(maxSize/total_no_elements_part_2));

let part2TitlesArray = new Array(maxSize);

//First I construct an array with 5 values 

for(let j=0;j<part2TitlesArray.length;j++){
  part2TitlesArray[j]= [j+lengthPart1Array];
}

//Then I fill up the index obtained from every_nth
for (let i = 0; i < part2Array.length; i++) {
    insertAtIndex = part2Array[i];
    var newArray =[parseInt(lengthPart1Array+insertAtIndex-1),"Title"+insertAtIndex];
    part2TitlesArray[insertAtIndex-1]= newArray;
}


//Similar iteration for Part3Titles array as well


var result = {
                "Part1":
                    part1Array,
                "Part2":
                    part2TitlesArray,
                "Part3":
                   part3TitlesArray
};
```

Is there any better way to achieve this? How can I distribute the values as per my requirement?.

Comment: sorry can you go over what u want for the input and outputs?

Comment: i.e. where is 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 coming from in the output, and why are the "Title [number]" seemingly randomly distributed amongst the values

Comment: 11,12,13,14,15 in part 3 are the indexes which need to be in sequence. For example Part1 array has 5 elements 1..5 and then Part2 array need to have from 6,7,8,9,10 and then Part 3 array need to have from 11..15.  Title[number] does not matter. It can be any string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build new arrays by looking to the length of the arrays.

```js
var titles = { "Part 1": [["1", "Title 1", 'A'], ["2", "Title 2", 'B'], ["3", "Title 3", 'C'], ["4", "Title 4", 'D'], ["5", "Title 5", 'E']], "Part 2": [["6", "Title 6", 'A1'], ["7", "Title 7", 'B1']], "Part 3": [["8", "Title 8", 'A2'], ["9", "Title 9", 'B2'], ["10", "Title 10", 'c2']] },
    length = Math.max(...Object.values(titles).map(({ length }) => length)),
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(titles)
        .map(([k, array], i) => [
            k,
            Array.from({ length }, (_, j) => {
                const 
                    left = (i * length + j + 1).toString(),
                    offset = Math.ceil((length - array.length) / 2);
                 
                return j < offset || j >= offset + array.length
                    ? [left]
                    : [left, ...array[j - offset].slice(1)]
            })
        ])
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, I will try it out later and comment here.

Comment: Hey @Nina,Is it possible to distribute array elements with equal gaps in between.

I have part2 array as: [["6"],["7"],["8", "Title ab"],["9", "Title cd"],["10"]] distributing element from middle. How can I change it to get output as [["6"],["7","Title ab"],["8"],["9", "Title cd"],["10"]]

So If I had 3 values in Part 2 array then the output would be:
[["6","Title ab"],["7"],["8","Title cd"],["9"],["10","Title ef"]]

Comment: it is possible, but not so easy, because it depends on the length and count of wanted items.